# What is the best strategy to a continuously running aggregation script?

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm about to implement sorting my data by popularity. I'm creating a separate index to log views of all items. I want to sort the items by `Popularity{Today,Week,Month,Year,AllTime}`. For this I need a continuously running script that will aggregate the data from the view index to the data index. I'm afraid that a continuously running script will put continuous high load on the server. Are there any good strategies to avoid performance issues and make this process low priority?

Comment: Have you looked into transform ? You could have a dedicated node for handling the transformation https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-node.html

Comment: A checked before, but I don't know how it can help in my case.

Comment: Well it does aggregation is I am not wrong. And it can automate them.

Comment: But when an entry is created, I need to set another query's results on another index. Even if that would work, I still cannot rely on the views to trigger the update, the aggregated data can change without even hitting a single view.